# Error with wrong tensor size in Neural Network in Pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, transfer-learning, pre-trained-model

### I want to use pre-trained AlexNet to classify non-classified images in my dataset and I get a **RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [3, 224, 224] at entry 0 and [4, 224, 224] at entry 19** in 417 cell of my Jupyter Notebook. Could you, please, help me with such a mistake.

I have a dataset with images of different rooms: bathroom, kitchen, living room, etc. So, I have 6 classes. I have 1547 pictures been classified, and I want to classify the other ones using a pre-trained Neural Network. I created a dataset in Pytorch, then I downloaded pre-trained AlexNet, and then I got such a mistake with the tensor's size. Please, could you help me?
[Colab with code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vi0gc5_k-3Alxp-_9Jyp5Jyvoe_lo9O9?usp=sharing)

[Picture of the cell with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvn3e.png)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-417-17d11cc21579> in <module>
      3     # Train phase
      4     model.train()
----> 5     for idx, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(data_loader['train']):
      6         optimizer.zero_grad()
      7         inputs = inputs.to(device)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    519             if self._sampler_iter is None:
    520                 self._reset()
--> 521             data = self._next_data()
    522             self._num_yielded += 1
    523             if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _next_data(self)
    559     def _next_data(self):
    560         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 561         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    562         if self._pin_memory:
    563             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     45         else:
     46             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]
---> 47         return self.collate_fn(data)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py in default_collate(batch)
     82             raise RuntimeError('each element in list of batch should be of equal size')
     83         transposed = zip(*batch)
---> 84         return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
     85 
     86     raise TypeError(default_collate_err_msg_format.format(elem_type))

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     82             raise RuntimeError('each element in list of batch should be of equal size')
     83         transposed = zip(*batch)
---> 84         return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
     85 
     86     raise TypeError(default_collate_err_msg_format.format(elem_type))

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py in default_collate(batch)
     54             storage = elem.storage()._new_shared(numel)
     55             out = elem.new(storage)
---> 56         return torch.stack(batch, 0, out=out)
     57     elif elem_type.__module__ == 'numpy' and elem_type.__name__ != 'str_' \
     58             and elem_type.__name__ != 'string_':

RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [3, 224, 224] at entry 0 and [4, 224, 224] at entry 19
```

Comment: What type of images you are using? If it's `png` there is probably 4th channel `alpha` that you need to get rid of.

Comment: @kacpo1 It's jpg type. For instance: https://a0.muscache.com/pictures/10272854/8dcca016_original.jpg